# Move Mouse - VBScript and Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vbscript, mouse, css-position

Found a script that uses Excel to move the mouse in VBScript. This is almost exactly what I am looking for for my project, however I need to alter a small bit to enable me to enter coordinates in the code for it to move the mouse specifically to those coordinates; the code currently uses the current mouse position and moves from that position - I need to be able to have the mouse move to an ABSOLUTE position, not a RELATIVE one.

Here's the VBS code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Excel, GetMessagePos, x, y, Count, Position

Set Excel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

GetMessagePos = Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro( _
    "CALL(""user32"",""GetMessagePos"",""J"")")
x = CLng("&H" & Right(Hex(GetMessagePos), 4))
y = CLng("&H" & Left(Hex(GetMessagePos), (Len(Hex(GetMessagePos)) - 4)))

Position = "+ 180"
Position = "- 180"
Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro ( _
    "CALL(""user32"",""SetCursorPos"",""JJJ""," & x & " " & Position & "," & y & " " & Position & ")")

WScript.Sleep (100)
WScript.Echo "Program Ended"
```

According to the code, the position of the mouse is moved from it's CURRENT POSITION +180 then -180. I need this code altered so I can put both the positions (in variable names X and Y) and use those to set the exact position of the mouse pointer.

I have messed around with the Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro part and checked out the documentation for the function to no avail. Please can you help? Thanks :)

EDIT: I'm using VBScript because the system I am creating this on is VERY locked down. I have no way of using any other technologies bar this one, so help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when you do this

```
Position = "+ 180"
Position = "- 180"
```

you're first setting `Position` to be "+180" and then immediately overwriting it to be "-180". There's no point in doing that.

To answer your question more specifically, replace this part:

```
x & " " & Position & "," & y & " " & Position
```

with something like this:

```
x & "," & y
```

Prior to that you'll have to say what the new coordinates of the cursor should be, e.g.

```
x = "111"
y = "222"
```

Also, all of this you don't need and can delete:

```
GetMessagePos = Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro( _
    "CALL(""user32"",""GetMessagePos"",""J"")")
x = CLng("&H" & Right(Hex(GetMessagePos), 4))
y = CLng("&H" & Left(Hex(GetMessagePos), (Len(Hex(GetMessagePos)) - 4)))
```

That's where you get the old cursor position, and you don't need this since you say yourself you don't want to set a relative position.

All in all your script should look something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Excel, x, y

Set Excel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

x = "111"
y = "222"
Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro ( _
    "CALL(""user32"",""SetCursorPos"",""JJJ""," & x & "," & y & ")")

WScript.Sleep (100)
WScript.Echo "Program Ended"
```