# Could not load automation class "Excel.Application" - VBScript Move Mouse

Tags: excel, vbscript, citrix

I'm using the code from my previous question : [Move Mouse - VBScript and Excel Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613703/move-mouse-vbscript-and-excel-macro)

My aim is to move the mouse using VBScript and this works through using Excel. The problem is, this runs fine on my home machine, which has Office 2007 on.

However, when running this script at work, I get the following error:

"Could not locate automation class named "Excel.Application""

The only difference I can see that these work computers have is that they have Office 2003 installed instead, so Excel.Aplacation needs to be changed to something else maybe?

Google yielded no useful results. I'm creating this in notepad. Can someone help? If I can get this working it's be pretty amazing.

Comment: Your code worked fine on my Excel 2003, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: After a bit of rooting, it MIGHT be the case that the Office Suite is installed on the server. How would I go about performing the same thing I want to, with limited access to administrative settings, if Excel is installed on the server? Citrix I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Excel cannot be referenced correctly on a Citrix environment.

A local copy of excel is most likely needed to reference this from the client hard drive (as it's actually referencing the server's installation on Citrix).